# I get null value from function in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to collect the return of this method but it gives me an error. If I put a `var_dump` inside the method, it reads the variable that I want to return, but outside the method, equating it to another variable gives me `null`.
I have tried to send the data by reference, but neither it works.
This is the code:

```
 public function restrictionMinimunBid(Request  $request, $karateka,  $bid)
    {
        $allKaratekas = Karateka::all()
        ->map(function ($allKaratekas) use ($karateka, $request, & $bid){
                if($karateka->id == $allKaratekas->id ){
                   if($request->bid > $allKaratekas->value){
                    $bidFilter =$request->bid;
                    var_dump($bidFilter);
                    return $bidFilter;
                    $msg ="The bid is more than the value of karateka /  Bid created.";
                    var_dump($msg);
                   }
                   else{
                       $error ="The bid is less than the value of karateka";
                       var_dump($error);
                   }
                }
        });
    }
```

And here it is where I want to get the value and it is null:

```
 $bidFilter = self::restrictionMinimunBid($request, $karateka, $bid);
 var_dump($bidFilter);
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `return` into your function

Answer (score 0):

```php
 public function restrictionMinimunBid(Request  $request, $karateka,  $bid)
    {

       return Karateka::all()
        ->map(function ($allKaratekas) use ($karateka, $request, & $bid){
                if($karateka->id == $allKaratekas->id ){
                   if($request->bid > $allKaratekas->value){
                    $bidFilter =$request->bid;
                    var_dump($bidFilter);
                    return $bidFilter;
                    $msg ="The bid is more than the value of karateka /  Bid created.";
                    var_dump($msg);
                   }
                   else{
                       $error ="The bid is less than the value of karateka";
                       var_dump($error);
                   }
                }
        })->filter(function($value, $key) {
    return  $value != null;
})[0];
    }
```

```php
 $bidFilter = $this->restrictionMinimunBid($request, $karateka, $bid);
```

you need to return the value.

Comment: Id I do that I return the collection... and I just want to return the value ```$bidFilter```

Comment: @AitorBallesteros have you tried my code? what's not working?

Comment: Yes I tried your code, It is working, but It is returning a object, and I want only to return the ```$bidFilter``` variable. Here is where I recieve null value...

Comment: Yes I saw, but I receive an object, not a string variable

Comment: @AitorBallesteros `$this->restrictionMinimunBid($request, $karateka, $bid);` this is returning the collection. When you do this `$bidFilter = $this->restrictionMinimunBid($request, $karateka, $bid);` you are using `$bidFilter` variable pointing to returned collection. and then you can `dd($bidFilter)` to get the retult.

Comment: @AitorBallesteros do still get `null` when using my code?

Comment: No, null not, but I get just the object with your code

Comment: @AitorBallesteros  what you want it to return?

Comment: The string variable ```$bidFilter```

Comment: The string variable `$bidFilter` is not in the method. how can you return it?

Comment: @AitorBallesteros The string variable `$bidFilter` there is no value, if you want to return it you will get the `null` result again

Comment: @AitorBallesteros you want to return `$msg ="The bid is more than the value of karateka /  Bid created.";` this?

Comment: No, the variable before that, where I have to return

Comment: @AitorBallesteros that's not a sting either, it's a string array.  do you want that?

Comment: When I do var_dump with this: ```$bidFilter =$request->bid;``` I have a string value.

Comment: @AitorBallesteros can you `dd($this->restrictionMinimunBid($request, $karateka, $bid))` and show me what's the result?

Comment: It's too long, I did with var_dump and I receive first the string and after an object:```string(4) "1240"
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#324 (1) {
["items":protected]=>
array(14) {
[0]=>
string(4) "1240"
[1]=>
NULL
[2]=>
NULL
[3]=>
NULL
[4]=>
NULL
[5]=>
NULL
[6]=>
NULL
[7]=>
NULL
[8]=>
NULL
[9]=>
NULL
[10]=>
NULL
[11]=>
NULL
[12]=>
NULL
[13]=>
NULL
}
}```

Comment: @AitorBallesteros see my updated code. I think this time should work

Comment: This print empty value: "".

Comment: @AitorBallesteros I think this time I got it working , please check my answer.

Comment: I recieve this:```string(4) "1240"
{
    "code": 500,
    "error_msg": "Undefined offset: 0"
} ``` I don't know why first print the number and after that error...

Comment: @AitorBallesteros can you `dd($this->restrictionMinimunBid($request, $karateka, $bid))` for me? and paste it in your question so I can see it better?

Comment: I have done, but I received the same error than before.  Because there is an error inside the function.